# How to get output in VsCode terminal with line numbers?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am getting output in VsCode terminal without the line numbers, so everytime when I have to count how many lines have been printed , I manually need to count them.
[image: This is how I am getting my output for now.]
[image: This is how I want it to be.]

Comment: then write a simple script that will read stdin and output line number and line content and pipe your output to this script

Comment: You mean to make change in every program to add a line number with each new line ?

Comment: No, make a filter like `head` or `tail`, you pipe the output of your program to the filter, you can do this in C++ or python or ..... Or you can write a simple AWK or SED script to do the trick

Comment: Any resources for it ? Where can i get a template for it or a tutorial ?